# PHP - Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php

So this error is killing me, heres the code:

```
$html = file_get_html('vids.html');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {

        echo $element->name

        }
```

Comment: Well, check what `$html` is... `var_dump($html)`.

Comment: `array(4) { [0]=> string(2) " " [1]=> string(101) " " [2]=> string(2) " " [3]=> string(2) " " } ` not very good with arrays so no idea what this means

Comment: So it is not an object. It is an array...

Comment: Does `vids.html` actually contain a `a` element?

Comment: is this your own plugin/function? if you could link us to the plugin/function it would help.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP's DOM—in case your PHP version is not below 5?

Comment: i have placed some old php here should be `$html = $file..` @Pekka yes it does. could i have a link to phps DOM function?

Comment: @Ricki: According to your edit, [`file()`](http://php.net/file) “reads entire file into an array”. So this is probably not what you want.

Comment: i agree, finding alternate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the simple_html_dom.php file first?

```
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
```

And is your vids.html in the same directory you are calling from?

Comment: the vids.html file is in the same directory

Comment: ?  Is your issue Fixed  ?  You accepted my answer, so I'm guessing so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should var_dump($element) inside the loop and see if it has the 'name' property set.  YOu could modify your condition and add isset() in the loop,

```
   foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
     if(isset($element->name)){
        echo $element->name;
     }
  }
```