# simple html dom not working properly, showing errors

Tags: php, html, cakephp, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using simple html dom to parse html page.....
This is my code..

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html($my_url);


foreach($html->find('div') as $ul) {
     echo $ul;
   }
```

And i have also tried many other ways . Still i get this error.
Error:

```
 Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

I have tried out with other tags as well...

```
  $html->find('a');
  $html->find('h3');
  //But still same above error
```

Can anyone plz help me out wit the error..Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `include` to `require` so it errors out if the include fails. Just to be sure that's actually being loaded.

Comment: Also, `$my_url` is not defined.

Comment: I have defined it, and i just did nt post in the above code......

Comment: @joeframbach Stil nt working dude....

Comment: post an output from print_r($html); after instantiation !

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');` before the `require`. Make sure all of your errors and notices are being shown,.

Comment: @KishorKundan for print_r i am getting empty output....and for var_dump i am getting bool(false)

Comment: Try this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190657/php-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190657/php-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object

Comment: I am pretty sure, simple_html_dom is not being included else there isn't much to it. can you post print_r(get_included_files()); after include

Comment: IMHO either url is invalid or html from that url is malformed.

Comment: files are being included, hers the output Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\myexample.php [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\simple_html_dom.php )

Comment: @peterm I even tried wit many urls, https://www.google.co.in/, etc still same error

Comment: Is there any bug in the simple_html_dom_parser ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i found out the solution, 
The solution is:-

> The latest version of simple_html_dom has got bugs in it.... So dont
>   use simplehtmldom_1_5 file from sourceforge... Better use
>   simplehtmldom_1_10 from sourceforge it works fine.

Bugs in simplehtmldom_1_5:-

> Url of any site doesnt work here. You can give url of html file , but
>   site url doesnt work  It is not identifying ur object $html after
>   reading the url....

Hope it helps people facing similar problem....

Comment: This is simply not true. I've been using 1.5 and it works using urls. You may get different results due to different versions and their handling of malformed html. For this the proper solution would be to move to a libxml-based parser such as phpquery. But that's a subject for a different question...

Comment: @pguardiario For me atleast 1.5 dint work. And as per my knowledge phpQuery has a poor documentation and support compared to simple dom

Comment: I understand that it didn't work for you, but not because 1.5 doesn't work with urls like you said. Rather, because the html was malformed and simple doesn't perform reliably with malformed html the way that libxml-based parsers do.

Comment: I literally tried with almost many urls

Comment: Well it works fine for me, which leads me to believe you're doing something silly.

Comment: Probably i may be doing silly......You win...

Comment: Look, Pavan, You can be testing with many malformed html urls, that's not how to prove your point. Test it with `http://www.google.com/` - if that gives you problems you will know there is something wrong with the library (or you're doing something silly like suppressing error messages). Otherwise you're just spreading FUD by complaining that there's a problem with the lib. Got it?

Comment: i have tried it with http://www.google.com/ and it is showing errors thats the reason i mentioned that it is gt error...

Answer (score 0):

You are using cakephp so you can not use it as like this.

You either need to create `vendor( for controller )` or `create helper( for view )`.

And one more `$html` is already reserved for `$html helper`.

For vendor loading

```
App::import('Vendor', 'HTMLDOM', array('file' => 'HtmlDom' . DS . 'simple_html_dom.php'));
```

For helper.

```
App::import('Helper', 'HtmlDom');
$NewHtmlDom = new SimpleHtmlDom; 

$fileContent = $NewHtmlDom->file_get_html($my_url);
```

Comment: I am able to include the files , i have tried it using simple php and also cake bt same errors in both of them

Comment: @PavanK that can not be possible as long as you put files in right directory and including correctly...also make sure that function is present inside simpledom php file.

Comment: Yes i checked and verified all, files are included properly and find function is also present..........